# What is the formal definition of a combinational logic?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, regular-expressions, computation-models

## Question Background

A finite-state machine can be defined as a 5-tuple as follows (Sipser, pg. 35):

[image: Definition of Finite Automaton]

The image below (taken from [the Wikipedia article on combinational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic)) seems to suggest that combinational logics can be used to define formal grammars that describe formal languages just the same as regular expressions/FSMs, pushdown automatons, and turing machines.

[image: Automata Theory]

## The Question

Is this, in fact, the case? And if so, **what is the formal definition of a combinational logic**? Is it a finite automata/5-tuple that has a transition function that always specifies a transition to it's one and only state (since it is time-indepedent)? **NOTE**:  I consider it inappropriate to couple boolean logic and digital circuitry to a mathematical model which should strive for maximal generalization

## References

Sipser, *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, (2nd Edition). Thompson Course Technology, 2006.

Comment: Automaton with a single state. Able to transform an input symbol to an output symbol.

Comment: I was leaning towards a definition like that. Do we have an official source though?

Comment: Indeed! My opinion is that "combinational logic" should be removed from the diagram in wikipedia. Instead as a part of automata theory it is part of complexity theory, as witnessed elsewhere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class#Boolean_circuits